# synchronize data template in a list box with a button

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, listbox

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="740">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:Leute x:Key="freunde"/>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="detail">

            <StackPanel  FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock x:Name="tb2"  Text="{Binding Path=Vorname}"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Path=Nachname}"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Path=Geburtsdatum, StringFormat = dd.MM.yy}"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>

    </DataTemplate>


</Window.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource freunde}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition  />
        <ColumnDefinition  />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ListBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource detail}" ItemsSource="{StaticResource freunde}"/>



    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Vorname" Margin="0,23,254,265"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Nachname" Margin="0,72,290,221"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Geburtsdatum" Margin="0,121,254,162" RenderTransformOrigin="0.086,1.118"></TextBlock>
    <TextBox  Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Vorname}" Margin="122,28,110,261"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Nachname}" Margin="122,71,110,221"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Geburtsdatum, StringFormat = dd.MM.yy}" Margin="122,120,110,162"/>

</Grid>
```

Hello,

im learning for a test, an this was one task of it. If i select an Item in the Listbox it wont show in the Textbox. Tried some things like element name and so on but it didnt work out. Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it

```
  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="true"
```

was missing here :

```
 <ListBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource detail}" ItemsSource="{StaticResource freunde}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" x:Name="list" />
```